# Recieving import error on Node after node install

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import

On Github I have a react app that I am trying to pull to my local machine. It does not have the node_modules folder so when I clone it I then run `npm install`. That works great but when I run `npm start` I get this error.

ERROR in ./src/util.js 1:40-123 
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/react-labs/movies 
/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. 
Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

I have tried adding `FAST_REFRESH=false` in the .env file but that didn't work.